# Send active workbook by e-mail but changing the name

Tags: excel, vba

So at the moment I have a workbook that gets sent to e-mail when pressing a button, but I want to change the name of the file when e-mailing it, how can I do this?

What I have right now is this code that just sends the file with the name of the current workbook, but I want to make it send it with the username of the person who sent the e-mail too by adding `Environ("UserName")` to it

```
With OutMail
   .to = "email1@example.com;email2@example.com"
   .Subject = "Your Answers " & Environ("Username")
   .Body = "Your answers are here"
   .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.Name
   .Send
End With
```

Comment: You must change the (active) workbook name before attaching it. Using SaveAs...

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, please. You have to change the workbook name before attaching it...

```
Dim fName As String
fName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Environ("Username")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=fName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault

With OutMail
      .to = "email1@example.com;email2@example.com"
      .Subject = "Your Answers " & Environ("Username")
      .Body = "Your answers are here"
      .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.Name
      .Send
End With
```